# 90 days to finish a task with every day probability to complete is 1/(i+1), what is a probability to finish within given time?

Tags: probability

For each day i (staring from 1) probability to finish a task at that i day is $\frac{1}{(1+i)}$. What is a probability to finish the task within 90 days?

I solved it as $\sum_{\substack{0<i<91}}$ P(to finish the task at day i)

and

P(to finish the task at day i) = $\frac{1}{(1+i)}$*$\sum_{\substack{0<j<i}}$ P(not finishing at day j)

I just want to check whether this answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the probability to finish on day $i$ assumes you did not finish earlier.  Otherwise the probability to finish by day $3$ is $\frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 \gt 1$.  On that assumption, the chance you do not finish by day $i$ is $$\prod_{k=1}^i \frac k{k+1}=\frac {i!}{(i+1)!}=\frac 1{i+1}$$
and the chance you finish by day $90$ is $\frac {90}{91}$